# Which clustering algorithm is suitable for one-dimensional Lists without knowing k?

Tags: c#, cluster-analysis, data-mining, k-means

I have a one dimensional List like this

```
public class Zeit_und_Eigenschaft
{
    [Feature]
    public double Sekunden { get; set; }
}

//...
List<Zeit_und_Eigenschaft> lzue = new List<Zeit_und_Eigenschaft>();
//fill lzue
```

lzue can be

```
lzue.Sekunden
1
2
3
4
8
9
10
22
55
...
```

Goal is to find clusters in that list, ie elements that could form groups like f.i. in this example

```
lzue.Sekunden
1
2
3
4

8
9
10

22

55
```

Which clustering algorithm is suitable(I don't know the number of clusters k)? GMM? PCA? Kmeans? Other?

Comment: possible duplicate of [partitioning an float array into similar segments (clustering)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17479944/partitioning-an-float-array-into-similar-segments-clustering)

Answer (score 9):

Don't look for *clustering* algorithms.

Clustering is a good term for *multivariate* data, but your data is one-dimensional, so you should look at much older *statistics* literature. E.g. Natural Breaks optimization.

Or just kernel density estimation. In fact, you will find the very same question *dozens* of times here on stackoverflow already...

[1D Number Array Clustering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11513484/1d-number-array-clustering)

[Cluster one-dimensional data optimally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7869609/cluster-one-dimensional-data-optimally?lq=1)

[partitioning an float array into similar segments (clustering)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17479944/partitioning-an-float-array-into-similar-segments-clustering?lq=1)

[Efficiently grouping similar numbers together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14077110/efficiently-grouping-similar-numbers-together?lq=1)

[Clustering values by their proximity in python (machine learning?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18364026/clustering-values-by-their-proximity-in-python-machine-learning?lq=1)

Answer (score 0):

There was a good article in MSDN magazine on this topic a few months ago. They used the k-means algorithm. Link:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj891054.aspx

Also, there are some videos on k-means clustering as part of Andrew Ng's online machine learning class. Link:

https://class.coursera.org/ml-003/lecture/preview

When you don't know k, there are some algorithms to search for a good value. Do a web search for k-means + elbow.