# Mahout Clustering with one dim K-means

Tags: hadoop, cluster-analysis, data-mining, mahout, k-means

Can I cluster data with one variable instead of many (What I had already test) using mahout K-means Algorithm ? if yes (I hope so :) )could you give me an Example of clustering and thinks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How big is your data? If it is not exabytes,  you would be better off without Mahout.

If it is exabytes, use sampling, and then process it on a single machine.

See also:

- [Cluster one-dimensional data optimally?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7869609/1060350)
- [1D Number Array Clustering](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11513484/1060350)
- [Which clustering algorithm is suitable for one-dimensional Lists without knowing k?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20230475/which-clustering-algorithm-is-suitable-for-one-dimensional-lists-without-knowing?lq=1)

and many more.

Mahout is not your general go-to place for data anlysis. It *only* shines when you have Google scale data. Otherwise, the overhead is too large.